# Javascript - Return in a function parameter another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

What i'm trying to do might sound simple.

I just need to make a callback with another function
Here is an example using jQuery.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    var colors;

    colors = function(col){
        return col;
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        colors(function(){alert('Orange');});
    });
})(jQuery);
```

So when the document be ready, i need to send an alert that says 'Orange' but i want to do it by returning a function.

If you know another way to do it please let me know.

Comment: Strictly speaking, what you're asking to do is not possible. The way you make an alert popup happen is by calling the `alert()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a function, you have to put `()` after it. Since `colors()` returns the function, put `()` after the call to `colors`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    colors(function(){alert('Orange');})();
});
```

More generally, the way you deal with callbacks is something like:

```
callback = getCallback(args);
callback();
```

Comment: This may very well be what the OP is (mysteriously) trying to do :)

Comment: I suspect it's a simplification -- he may be calling a function that returns a function from a table of some kind.

Comment: i'm creating a plugin, for animations, so when de animation ends, if the user want, can make a callback